# C++ Class Object inside another class

Tags: c++, class, object

It keeps me getting this error in `Event.h`:

> field ‘group’ has incomplete type ‘Group’

For context, I want to have a class `Group` which has an owner (from class `Person`) and it consists of a vector of people (class `Person`):

Group.h

```cpp
class Person;
#include "Person.h"

Class Group
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Person> people;
        int size = 0;
        Person owner;
    public:
        Group(Person owner);
        ~Group();
}
```

In the `Person` class, I want to have just a vector of lists (class List, not important for this specific error). Note that in the `Person` class I have a constructor `Person(int id);`

In the `Event` class, I want to have a group of people invited that can be saved as a `Group` class:

Event.h

```cpp
class Group;
#include "Group.h"

class Event
{
    private:
        std::string tittle;
        std::string description;
        bool locked;
        bool checked;
        Group group;

    public:
        Event(std::string tittle);
        ~Event();
}
```

Why can't I have a `Person` owner on my group?

Edit:
I don't know why, but now it works. I guarded everything with just `#pragma once` and maybe I changed something in the way I compiled. Thanks for all answers :)

Comment: Yes, why? What blocks you? What are the symptoms of failure? Please provide a [mre] (ideally single file), with all info on errors.

Comment: `Class` should be `class` (case-sensitive). Also, semicolons are missing after definitions of your classes. This makes me believe you didn't post your real code. You can [edit] your post to include the real code (make sure you're running and posting the same version). Also, you can clarify your question by posting your `Person.h`. You might have to delete unneeded stuff from it before posting. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You are defining something out of order. Perhaps the #ifdef guards.

This compiles just fine:

```cpp
class Person {};

class Group
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Person> people;
        int size = 0;
        Person owner;
    public:
        Group( Person owr );
        ~Group();
};

class Event
{
    private:
        std::string tittle;
        std::string description;
        bool locked;
        bool checked;
        Group group;

    public:
        Event(std::string tittle);
        ~Event();
};
```

Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/f785vK1dq

Comment: Oh dear, making a clean single file MRE just solves the problem. What a surprise.... ;-)

Comment: That is EXACTLY what #include does @Yunnosch

Comment: I doubt it. `Class` -> `class` is not performed by any include.... Note however, that my first comment was celebrating your answer, not attacking it.

Comment: The C++ preprocessor will expand all the includes in memory and only then pass it as a single file to the actual compiler. This is very common knowledge. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/preprocessor-output-of-cpp-file/

Comment: I do not contradict. I wonder what your point is. You intend that to explain how the preprocessor turned "Class" into "class"?

Comment: @Yunnosch No, I thought you were criticizing my approach of adding everything to the same file to show on Godbolt. We are on the same page then.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine for me ([Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/eEiBE2G-r)):

Person.h

```cpp
#ifndef Person_H
#define Person_H

class Person
{
};

#endif
```

Group.h

```cpp
#ifndef Group_H
#define Group_H

#include "Person.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Group
{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector<Person> people;
        int size = 0;
        Person owner;
    public:
        Group(Person owner) : owner(owner) {}
};

#endif
```

Event.h

```cpp
#ifndef Event_H
#define Event_H

#include "Group.h"
#include <string>

class Event
{
    private:
        std::string tittle;
        std::string description;
        bool locked = false;
        bool checked = false;
        Group group;

    public:
        Event(std::string tittle) : tittle(tittle), group(Person{}) {}
};

#endif
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Event.h"

int main()
{
    Event evt("title");
    return 0;
}
```